# getting error:Error creating bean with name '*': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repo'; n

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

> Error:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'issueTemplateServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repo'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.conseco.repository.IssueTemplateRepo' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1395)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:849)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:400)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:291)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4840)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5303)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1407)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1397)
>       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.conseco.repository.IssueTemplateRepo' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1654)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1213)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1167)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:593)
>       ... 24 more

My code:

IssueTemplateController:

```
package com.conseco.controller;




import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.conseco.dao.IssueTemplateInfo;
import com.conseco.service.IssueTemplateService;


@Controller
public class IssueTemplateController {

    @Autowired
  IssueTemplateService service;



    @RequestMapping("/new")
    public ModelAndView create()
    {

        System.out.println("service: "+service);
        ModelAndView mav=new ModelAndView("index");
        System.out.println("1..................");
        IssueTemplateInfo issue=new IssueTemplateInfo();
        issue.setSDT("123456");
        issue.setAnalysis("test");
        issue.setApplicaiton("AWD");
        issue.setBatch("no");
        issue.setBusinessImpact("N/A");
        issue.setDescription("will describe later");
        issue.setEMER("N/A");
        issue.setImpDate("25th");
        issue.setPermanentFix("TBT");
        issue.setQCDefect("234");
        issue.setRootCause("unknown");
        issue.setSeverity(3);
        issue.setStatus("Inprogress");
        issue.setWorkAround("a lot to work on");
        service.save(issue);

        System.out.println("4..............");


        return mav;
    }

}


MyFrontController:



package com.conseco.controller;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

import com.conseo.config.WebMvcConfig;

public class MyFrontController extends  AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer{

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new Class[] {WebMvcConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new String[] {"/"};
    }

}




IssueTemplateRepo:
package com.conseco.repository;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;


import com.conseco.dao.IssueTemplateInfo;


public interface IssueTemplateRepo extends CrudRepository<IssueTemplateInfo, String> {

}



IssueTemplateService:


package com.conseco.service;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.conseco.dao.IssueTemplateInfo;


public interface IssueTemplateService {


    IssueTemplateInfo save(IssueTemplateInfo issue);
}



IssueTemplateServiceImpl:
package com.conseco.service;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.conseco.dao.IssueTemplateInfo;
import com.conseco.repository.IssueTemplateRepo;

@Service
public class IssueTemplateServiceImpl implements IssueTemplateService {

    @Autowired
    private IssueTemplateRepo repo;

    public IssueTemplateRepo getRepo() {
        return repo;
    }

    public void setRepo(IssueTemplateRepo repo) {
        this.repo = repo;
    }

    @Override
    public IssueTemplateInfo save(IssueTemplateInfo issue) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return repo.save(issue);
    }

}





WebMvcConfigurer:
package com.conseo.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;



@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan({"com.conseco.service","com.conseco.controller","com.conseco.repository","com.conseco.dao"})
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

}
```

Comment: Hi, it would be nice, if you add some words what you're trying to do.

Comment: i'm trying to insert values in db using spring data jpa which has  pre defined  save or update or delete defined crud repository

Answer (score 0):

Add the annotation `@Component` on the interface:

```
@Component
public interface IssueTemplateRepo extends CrudRepository<IssueTemplateInfo, String> {

    }
```

After you add the `@Component` annotation will become a spring bean and it can be managed managed by the Spring IoC container.

Comment: @Santhosh use `@Repository` instead of `@Component`